# Building theme so user can change header image

Tags: loop, images, headers

My Google-Fu is letting me down so I'm trying it here.

I'm building a theme and I want the customer to be able to change the header image him/herself in the wp-admin. How do I go about this?

As I said my Google-Fu has been embarrasingly lacking on this one so even a link to where to start would be fantastic.

Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly, there is a Codex page named ["Custom Headers"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, I am an idiot.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is answered with nothing more than a Codex link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can add theme support in your functions file for a Custom Header page using this code which also enables you to add a default size and selector class which you can style with CSS.

   ```
    add_theme_support( 'custom-header', array( 
   'width'           => 320,
   'height'          => 60,
   'header-selector' => '.site-title a',
   'header-text'     => false
     ) );
   ```
2. Or this method enables the user to change the header image in every page.

You can add this feature using custom fields with a header hook which isn't difficult.

The hardest part would be [coding the meta box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) to display on all edit screens however the Codex offers a very basic example.

Another solution would be to use the code from the Twenty Eleven default theme which enables the use of Featured Images as header images on every single post or page. Slick featured for a theme in my opinion as it already includes the meta box.